# ODP.NET - disable auto commit

Tags: c#, oracle, transactions, odp.net, odp.net-managed

Is there a simple way how to disable auto commit when using ODP.NET? I want to start transactions using SET TRANSACTION command, not using Connection.BeginTransaction neither TransactionScope. Also I want to any DML start transaction (if not started yet) but not commit changes until I issue COMMIT command. I know that other Oracle providers (JDBC or Devart) support this but I would like to achieve the same behavior with ODP.NET.

I also found there is private field probably controlling that in managed version of ODP.NET but it's hidden within implementation of physical connection which is difficult to access via OracleConnection instance. It also seems in unmanaged version this setting is outside Oracle.DataAccess.dll assembly.

Comment: Not my area, but: _To execute an explicit transaction, you first acquire an OracleTransaction object from an OracleConnection object by invoking the BeginTransaction method. Note that this is the only way to acquire the transaction object_. From here: [http://www.oracle.com/au/products/database/o39odpnet-087387.html](http://www.oracle.com/au/products/database/o39odpnet-087387.html)

Comment: This is just simple description how to control transactions using invoking methods on connection object. I don't want that. I want the transaction to be not committed when issuing first DML without explicitly starting the transaction using BeginTransaction/new TransactionScope. Basically the default SQL*Plus behavior.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't like `Connection.BeginTransaction`?

Comment: I have my own SQL editor where you can execute any ad-hoc SQL command and if I want to start a transaction using SET TRANSACTION I would need to explicitly check every command that is going to be executed if it's SET TRANSACTION and which isolation level I need to choose as  parameter in BeginTransaction. Not saying that the method doesn't support READ ONLY. Of course it isn't a problem to actually do it but I don't like such a solution. Especially when other providers have the AutoCommit setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to disable autocommit with ODP.NET is to use BeginTransaction/new TransactionScope.

You can make it clear to your users in your UI that autocommit is on by default and they can turn if off by clicking a toolbar button, etc at which time you can call Begin Transaction using some options you can place in a properties or options page.

This is exactly what we do with our Oracle Developer Tools in the Query Window.

Another possible thing to look into is anonymous PL/SQL for sending up a block of SQL statements at once.

As for "SET TRANSACTION", I am not sure if it will have an effect if you have already done a "BeginTransaction" but you can document that this command is not supported if that is the case (we would have to do the same in our query window if so).

If you would like ODP.NET to be enhanced with this feature at some future date, you may want to put in a request over at the ODP.NET feature request page:

http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=18357:46

Comment: Thanks. I added missing features (more than just this :-)) there. Although I consider this solution (I use it already) more as a workaround than the proper one the answer is accepted.

I can't use anonymous block because I don't want to execute different statement(s) than those written in the editor.